# Blob byte array in XML to Image

Tags: c#, image, arrays, blob

I am getting a XML File to generate a preview, in a format like this:

`<PARAM>
        <LABEL>Preview 16x16</LABEL>
        <ID>{03F5C6D3-ABCD-4889-B3AA-C3524C62FA1C}</ID>
        <LAYER>-1</LAYER>
        <VALUE>
            <BLOB>
                /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcHBw8LCwkMEQ8S
                EhEPERETFhwXExQaFRERGCEYGh0dHx8fExciJCIeJBweHx7/2wBDAQUFBQcGBw4ICA4eFBEU
                Hh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh7/wAAR
                CAAOABADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAA
                AgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkK
                FhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWG
                h4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl
                5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREA
                AgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYk
                NOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOE
                hYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk
                5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDP+IXxH+Ilr4/1DRrLxZqUrjUTbMLKdtsz
                eZgLCgHyDHy4GSeee9dT4Z8G/FjxHrmla3Y3bRlRtl1iW9ztGTnlXLS47YG0nrXQa78Bda07
                U7jXNM1nS9yGVhJLHJvk8wkEkchWAYjcuDzxggGuB8K6v49i8X28Wg+IodMkaUQFI4sQSEt1
                eM5B42qOPlVVVcAV5M8NKdSMW/cV3vrfXyb/AB/I+4+sVUnPCUVeyV3Z3010923krdPU/9k=
            </BLOB>
        </VALUE>
    </PARAM>`

I need to convert the `<BLOB>` section into an Image. I access the Element Value like this:

```
string clean = valueC.ElementAt(0).Value.Replace("\t", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty);
```

I've tried to read it into a MemoryStream and convert to Image:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(blob, 0, blob.Length);
ms.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
Image i = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

In this way I get "Parameter not valid exception" at getting the Image.
I've also tried to save it directly into a File:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(label + ".jpg", FileMode.Create))
{
    fs.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
}
```

But when I try to open the generated file, displays a message about damage in it.

I know that encoding is important, I've already tried ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-7 and this:

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bf.Serialize(ms, clean);
ms.Seek(0, 0);
byte[] blob = ms.ToArray();
```

I dont know what else to do. I'll appreciate if somebody can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your data is in Base64 format so you first need to decode it and then save it as an image.